# Django Form, check validate before submit. (HTML)

Tags: html, validation, django-forms

For a regular html form, I could use java script to validate input onsubmit, which means the submit button is work only for a valid input, hence no http response required. 
However, I am unable to do the same thing for a django form. 
A Django form in html is simply as {{form}}.
for example {{form.title}} is the form for title.
So I am looking for a way to validate the Django form at front end (in HTML). only the valid input would be post

Answer (score 0):

Not Django specific. Its a frontend Javascript framework Job. Or if you are certain that your webapps's target audience is all latest browser oriented, supporting HTML5, then go for HTML form validations ([source](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/forms/html5forms/)) .

If you do not want to go for client side validation and re-use your Django's validation code, then I would suggest serialize and submit the form using ajax. You could get a JSON reply and parse it using javascript, or get the whole updated form back(using Django's template engine) and update the DOM. In case you need a sample, let me know which method you are opting for. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Include jquery validator

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/jquery.validate.min.js' %}"></script>
```

In contact.html

Loader .gif while you send form

```
<div id="loadingDiv" class="hiddenClass">
<p><img src="{% static "images/ajax-loader.gif" %}" alt="loader" ><br/>Please wait... while we...<p>
</div>
```

your form code in contact.html

```
<form method="post" action="/contact/send/"  id="contact_wrap">

<div class="name">
<label class="label">Name  <span class="required">*</span></label>
<input name= "firstname" id="firstname" class="inputtext"  type="text" maxlength="20" size="12" placeholder="First Name"/>
</span>
</div>

<-- your code -->

</form>
```

submit button in contact.html

```
<div class="button">
<input id="submitform" class="submitform" type="submit" name="submitform" value="Send" />
</div>
```

script to validate form in contact.html

```
<script>
$(function() {
    $( "#contact_wrap" ).validate({

        errorClass: "my-error-class", //apply a css class for error if you have style for valid
        validClass: "my-valid-class", //apply a css class for error if you have style for error

        rules: {
            firstname: {
                required: true
            },

        },
        messages: {
            firstname: {
                required: "Please enter your First Name."                         
            },
        },
    });

});
</script>
```

To check validation before submit in contact.html
show ajax-loader.gif from loading div

```
<script>
$( "#submitform" ).click(function() {
        if ($('#contact_wrap').valid()) $( "#loadingDiv" ).removeClass( "hiddenClass" ).addClass( "showClass" );
});
</script>
```